# Publishing ClickOnce results in Publish has encountered an error. The profile could not be saved

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, clickonce, publish

On a number of different projects when using ClickOnce to deploy I run into trouble when publishing a new version of the WinForms app to a fileshare using an existing profile:

```
Publish has encountered an error.
The profile could not be saved.

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users\{mywindowsusername}\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmp5504.tmp"
```

The contents of which are:

```
28/09/2023 11:43:23
Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: The profile could not be saved. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An equivalent project (a project with the same global properties and tools version) is already present in the project collection, with the path "C:\data\tfs\project_number\project_name-Development\Solution\SpiSt.WinApp\Properties\PublishProfiles\myprofile.pubxml". To load an equivalent into this project collection, unload this project first.
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidOperation(String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadedProjectCollection.AddProject(Project project)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.OnAfterRenameLoadedProject(String oldFullPathIfAny, Project project)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ProjectImpl.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, IDirectoryCacheFactory directoryCacheFactory, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.NewFx.Persistence.MsBuildFilePersister.UpdateAsync(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 profileData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.NewFx.Persistence.MsBuildFilePersister.StoreAsync(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 profileData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.NewFx.Persistence.MsBuildFilePersister.StoreAsync(String filePath, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 profileData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClickOnce.Publish.Util.<StorePubXmlAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClickOnce.Publish.ProfileVisual.<PostPublishStepAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Nexus.PublishProfilesServiceImpl.ServerProjectProfilesManager.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__73.MoveNext()
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, .net6.0-windows, WinForms application.

Any ideas how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Visual Studio uses the logged in account when creating the profile.

The login credentials I had used to log into Visual Studio were incorrect/invalid.  Visual Studio prompted me to re-enter my credentials when I clicked on my account icon on the far right of the menu bar.

I logged Visual Studio out of my Microsoft account and then I was able to publish my projects successfully.